# symfony shortCodes bundle

Tags: symfony, shortcode

i have used laravel shortcodes (https://github.com/webwizo/laravel-shortcodes) with success, it is a nice bundle.

the question is: is there any bundle like this for symfony 3.x?

what this essentially do is take formatted string like [myString] with some optional parameters like [myString param1="abc" param2="def" ...] from a rendered blade / twig and looks for a controller / function etc. to resolve "myString". it passes the params to the controller, and the whole [...] stuff is replaced with the returned output. and it is done recursivly, so the result may contain another [myString2 ...] and so on. this is very useful in CMS building.

does anyone know anything like this for symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bundle that looks exactly what you are searching for:

https://github.com/mweimerskirch/MWShortcodeBundle

Comment: Yes, I know this one, this is the correct answer. The only problem, (well, not really a problem, just a bit of added work for every shortcode) is that i have to define every shortcode as a service.

Comment: the ideal sollution (i belive) would be to place all the handlers in a folder lets call it for ex. AppBundle/ShortCodeServices and at some point the framework would read all the handler classes in that folder. I managed to do this in Laravel and it worked like a charm: i just added a new file like MyTag.php in a folder, and i triggered reading and registering all shortcodes at the app init.

Comment: this way i could use all the shortcodes in ckeditor (i wrote a small CKEditor plugin in JS to get all the available shortcodes and list them in a selectbox), so it was supereasy to use all the shortcodes in the CMS. do you have any idea for stuff like this in symfony?

Comment: (to be honest im just beginning symfony, so, i dont have mutch experience with how it works - but i have 15 years of php dev, so im not a junior in the field.... maybe you guys have a good clue that can save me a few days of trial and error....). anyway, thanks.